# Recieve a POST JSON object inside PHP

Tags: php, ajax

I'm using React superagent to POST an object to a Php file so I can INSERT the data in Mysql database. I can't figure out how Php will receive this object.

React superagent:

```
submitData () {
Request.post('url')
.set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
.send('{"first_name":"John", "last_mane":"Doe"}')
.end()
 }
```

Php post.php

```
 $json=json_decode(stripslashes(), true); 

 $sql = "INSERT INTO myTable (first_name, last_name)
 VALUES ('', '')";

 if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
   echo "New record created successfully";
 } else {
   echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
 }
```

Comment: file_get_contents('php://input')

Comment: depends on PHP  configuration, `$_POST` and `$_REQUEST` should/can also contain data already as an array.

Comment: I'm having trouble with the superagent returning 500 error. Don't know if I need to add .end() with a callback function. Testing this out today.

Comment: Okay, I'm getting a server 500 error trying to echo $data_back using $data_back = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));  I do see the data in the Header as Form Data

Comment: @ShahafAntwarg This worked. $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
print_r($data); echo $data["first_name"]; Thanks